# How to use Android TTS in Arabic

Tags: android, text-to-speech

My application implements the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener interface, and I'm trying to let it speak Arabic letters, but it seems that it doesn't support Arabic.

What should I do?

Here is the code that sets the language, but Arabic is not supported:

```
mTts = new TextToSpeech (this, this); 
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Please Post the code.

Comment: I posted the statement required for setting the language, Arabic is not one of the options

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is clearly outdated. The current version of Google TTS, as of Feb 2021, supports Arabic language.

Answer (score 1):

Arabic is not supported by the default Google TTS engine. You will need to install a third-party TTS engine that supports Arabic such as eSpeak or [SVOX Arabic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.svox.classic.langpack.ar_xa_male_trial).

Comment: I did install it but I didn't know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

To use Arabic language, You should use

```
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar"));
```

instead of the following line

```
mTts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
```